# Field Not Generated in SRRS from Stored Procedure

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, pivot

I Exec one procedure to generate column and use in SRRS dataset :

here's my SP :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[CrossTab_MultiLV] 
(   @Select varchar(2000),
    @Pivots1Col varchar(100),
    @Summaries varchar(500),
    @GroupBy varchar(100),
    @OtherCols varchar(1000) = Null)

AS
set nocount on
set ansi_warnings on


declare @Vals varchar(8000);
set @Vals = '';

set @OtherCols= isNull(', ' + @OtherCols,'')


create table #temp  (Pivots1 varchar(100))
insert into #temp
exec ('select distinct convert(varchar(100),' + @Pivots1Col + ',101) as Pivots1 FROM (' + @Select + ') A')


select @Vals = @Vals + ', ' +
    replace(replace(@Summaries,'(','(CASE WHEN ' + @Pivots1Col + '=''' + Pivots1 +  ''' THEN '),')[', ' END) as [' + Pivots1 )
    from #Temp
order by Pivots1

drop table #Temp

exec ( 'select ' + @GroupBy + @OtherCols + @Vals +
       ' from (' + @Select + ') A GROUP BY ' + @GroupBy)


set nocount off
set ansi_warnings on
```

from sp above I just want to process something and generate field by those SP Produce multiple column , but only show the two first column

:

```
range   TotalAccount    CL_Only CL_Only_Have_Rate   CL_Only_No_Rate EU_CL   EU_CL_Have_Rate EU_CL_No_Rate   EU_Only EU_Only_Have_Rate   EU_Only_No_Rate
12  3   1   1   0   2   2   0   0   0   0
```

it'll only show :  `range`  `TotalAccount` column , is there any mistake in my stored procedure ??

Answer (score 1):

I would abandon the dynamic stored procedure design - SSRS does not work with these.

Instead I would present the data with fixed columns and use a Column Group in the SSRS design.

Comment: Oh so, true that SRRS doesn't support dynamic query like mine ?